# How to enable transient prompt only for enter key pressed but show full prompt for any other command executed

Tags: powershell, oh-my-posh

I am trying to adjust a theme(**atomic.omp.json** in this case) so that when just the enter key is pressed the transient prompt takes over, but when any other key/command is passed the usual decorated prompt shows up.

I am not able to get it working. It only shows the transient prompt everytime.
The customized verison can be found [here](https://github.com/akmalick/oh-my-posh/blob/3eb81c47b6bf12d01b7cba6e3ceff9382780f227/themes/atomic-transient.omp.json#L275C3-L281C5)

Below is what I have and what I am trying to acheive. Even in cases where just the enter key is pressed several times the expectation is that the usual prompt should show once at the start.

[image]